# Rails, paperclip, uploading a photo from a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

How can I upload a file with paperclip via the console or a in a rake task? I'm a little unsure how this works without a form. Has anyone dealt with this?

---

**update**

So I found this:

```
image = Image.new(:storage => File.open('/path/to/my/image.png', rb))
```

But I guess this makes my question a little simpler, say my photo was actually online (at varying domains) and I wanted to take it with paperclip and transform it and upload it to my server. Is it possible to somehow give `File.open` a url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a shot.

```
require 'open-uri'
image = Image.new(:storage => open("http://path.to.the/image.png"))
```

Worked when I tried it in my terminal I just did:

```
require 'open-uri'
image = open("https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjKuQ.jpg")
```

which resulted in:

```
=> #<File:/var/folders/Zo/ZoJYH-A6Eg8GQ3pV0fIyhU+++TU/-Tmp-/open-uri20101117-5813-1h64t5k>
```

Comment: Hugo is right here, you just need to pass a File object to the accessor setup on your model.

Comment: Ryan, I think the problem I have is that I'm using S3 as my storage., any Ideas?

Comment: Finnaly this method solved my problem to move photos from other platform! But there is still one problem left. Using this method, paperclip saves photo without extension, because it gets it from the temp file. How to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Oh I have found it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523171/paperclip-upload-from-url-with-extension. Thanks for the first steps!

Answer (score 1):

However, it saves the files as "open-uri12345sdf-1301fp." (without extension) in database. How we save original file name in photo_file_name field.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a hack I think but I'd just replicated the files with ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new object within my migration and ran it like that.